# {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to login to our Application. When I  input the username and the password and click login. It throws an error in the API. Saying: Incorrect Syntax near the keywoard 'IF'.
Here is the image for full exception details.
[Full Exception Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izxnx.png)

I tried to debug the solution and it starts from here:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("checkUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage IsUserActive(string userNames)
{
    try
    {
        var isActive = _userService.IsUserActive(userNames);
        return Helper.ComposeResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, isActive);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
        
}
```

After this, it will then be redirected to this method/function:

```
public bool IsUserActive(string username)
{
    try
    {
        var result = RetrieveAll().Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username));
        return result.Any();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
        
}
```

After this function, it will then be redirected to below function.
Then it will throw the exception in this line of code specifically in

`return GetDbSet<User>().Where(x => x.DeleteFlag == false).OrderByPropertyName("LastName", SortDirection.Ascending);`

```
public IQueryable<User> RetrieveAll()
{
    try
    {
        return GetDbSet<User>().Where(x => x.DeleteFlag == false).OrderByPropertyName("LastName", SortDirection.Ascending);
            
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e; 
    }
}
```

1. GetDbSet Contains this line of code.

```
    protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
       return Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

2. OrderByPropertyName Contains this line of code.

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, SortDirection direction)
    {
        return ApplyOrdering(query, attribute, direction, "OrderBy");
    }
```

I don't know what's wrong or where is that "IF" coming from or where should I edit for me to go proceed in logging in the application. I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: X. Username == username

Comment: `RetrieveAll()` methods are evil. Don't do that. They force the program to transmit all the records from the database every time, instead of applying the filtering inside the database, before transmitting the data.  This one isn't quite so bad, because it's stillan IQueryable, but it's still not a good pattern. Also `throw e` is bad, because it loses the stack trace. Just `throw` (no `e`) is better.